# How to handle SelectedValue changing in ListBox correctly (WPF, C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, selectedvalue

I must handle `SelectedValue` property changing to refresh some dependent UI elements when a user selects some item in a `ListBox`. I use `SelectedValue` because I need to know a concrete value of the item, not an index in the `ListBox` (the index may be different under variuos circumstances) or something another. My `ListBox` is binded to a `DataTable` and `SelectedValue` contains ID of a row in the table.

The problem is that when I try to get `SelectedValue` of the `ListBox` within `SelectionChanged` event handler, I receive a **prior** value, **not the current**! So, after I spent about a hour searching for ways of solving this problem, I noted that it is relatively well-known, but solutions I've seen do not seem to be very clear. Nevertheless, I "compiled" few ideas I have encountered to the next working snippet of code:

```
((DataRowView)this.LISTBOXNAME.SelectedItem)["ID"]
```

where `this` is my current window and `SelectedItem` may be casted to `DataRowView` as the `ListBox` is binded to a `DataTable` as I've mentioned before. This line of code gives a proper value of the selected `ListBoxItem`.

But anyway, I still want to know *how to make `SelectedValue` get proper value directly*?  Is it possible? Or, maybe, must I use another event (not `SelectionChanged`)? And if it is impossible, can somebody explain me the way of thinking of kind guys from Microsoft and why that property has such a feature?

Comment: Normally there is an event that occurs after the update. You are seeing the values during the selection change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedValueChanged` event works fine for getting the correct `SelectedValue` property, so I think the issue may be with how your listbox is setup.

You say you have it bound to a `DataTable`, so the items in your collection are `DataRowView` objects.

If you set `SelectedValuePath` to something like `"Id"`, then the `SelectedValue` property will attempt to set the `SelectedValue` to `DataRowView.Id`, which I don't think is a valid property.

Your two alternatives here are to either

- Build a collection of objects with proper properties to use for the `SelectedValue`

  ```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
           SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}"
           SelectedValuePath="Id" ... />
  ```

  where `MyCollection` is a collection of objects that each contain an `.Id` property.
- Or use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`, and work with your `DataRowView` objects as you are now. `SelectedItem` will be set to the selected item in your collection, which is of type `DataRowView`, so the code you have posted is how it is accessed.

  ```
  ((DataRowView)this.LISTBOXNAME.SelectedItem)["ID"]
  ```

Of the two, the first approach is usually preferred for WPF.

---

**Edit:** Here's an answer to [your question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591944/how-to-handle-selectedvalue-changing-in-listbox-correctly-wpf-c/28592850?noredirect=1#comment45496399_28592850) below since it was too long to fit in a comment.

A `ListBox` is meant to be bound to a collection of items. When you set the ItemsSource to a `DataTable`, you are really binding to a collection of `DataRowView` objects.

There are 3 ways to get selected item from here: `SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex`, and `SelectedValue`.

- `SelectedItem` returns you the object that is selected. In this case, that's the `DataRowView` object, which is why you can cast it to a DataRowView.
- `SelectedIndex` returns you the index of the selected item within the data source.
- `SelectedValue` can only be used if you have also set the `SelectedValuePath` property. `SelectedValuePath` tells WPF which property on each data object contains the "Value" of the item, so if you set it to something like `"Id"`, it will try to find the `.Id` property on each object. In your case, there is no valid property on object `DataRowView` that would contain your Id column data, so this doesn't work.

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: And use the set to deal with refresh some dependent UI elements.

Comment: Hm, thanks. But I need to think over your answer a little. :)

Comment: Well, maybe my questions will seem to be stupid but nevertheless I want to ask them. I don't understand two things. The first is how is it possible to attempt to set the `SelectedValue` to `DataRowView.Id`? I didn't find such a property in a `DataRowView` object. The second is why doesn't it work correctly with a table (it is a collection of `DataRow`s, isn't it)? 

I bind my list to a table, and then bind some values of the list items to columns (such as "ID", "NAME" and so on) of the table.

I'll try to check your advice tomorrow, using my own collection instead of `DataTable`.